# Malware scanning in JFrog Artifcatory

Tags: artifactory

We plan to use generic package type for JFrog Artifcatory repository.

We are using Enterprise + which includes XRay as well.

Does Artifactory scans the files/artifacts uploaded for malware as well ?

AFAIK XRay works on certain package types and just checks if there is any vulnerability in the uploaded artifact.

Best Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Saurav your understanding is correct. Xray can check for vulnerabilities in artifacts that are uploaded to Artifactory. You can perform [on demand](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Xray+On-Demand+Binary+Scan) scanning for identifying vulnerabilities in your artifacts without uploading to Artifactory too.
Xray's functionality is to find out license vulnerabilities and security vulnerabilities. But Xray's functionality is not to identify the malware at this moment.
Also, the supported packages for Xray are mentioned in [this page](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-packages-and-repositories-are-supported-in-xray-for-indexing/).